# Create right to left and bidirectional PDF files in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, bidi, docmosis

Can anyone recommend a library who really support RTL languages such as Hebrew or arabic, and also Supports links, support images, thumbnails/in-place images, Handle large spread-sheets, set filters and page breaks and good performance – very important criteria-

I started to use PDFKit who is really good, but the language support is awful and the data that we work with cannot be manipulated, because of that we need to change the library, the price is not a problem. Someone recommended Docmosis, someone has experience with it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docmosis has customers that have been generating RTL documents for successfully for years.  Docmosis supports the image handling requirements you mention and large data sets, but has no direct spreadsheet functionality.

I suggest doing a free trial (please note I work for Docmosis) and asking their support team about specific points of interest.  The cloud is the easiest way to test functionality (since you have no install or setup to do) even if you wouldn't choose to use cloud for your actual deployment.